# How to create event listener on Window.Blur () event?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

Javascript: How to create event listener on `Window.Blur()` event?

Comment: Are you using jQuery or any other JS library or are we just talking about straight JS?

Comment: It's the same as with any other event listener -- what did you try so far?

Comment: OK, this is funny: I wrote an answer, but wanted to do a quick test of it.  It worked, and then I couldn't get back to this page to post my answer because the tab I was testing my script in would alert every time it lost focus.  Meanwhile patrick answered.

Comment: @JacobM - I've been an alert() hostage before. Not fun. :o)

Comment: I have too, but this was the first time I did it to myself.  :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
window.onblur = function() {
   //say goodbye
};
```

[According to quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html) `onfocus` and `onblur` are available on the `window` in most browsers.

Comment: Only thing I'll add is that older version of Internet Explorer didn't handle this correctly; you can work-around using document.onfocusout.

Answer (score 15):

It's better to use `addEventListener` instead of a property, this way you can set multiple handlers and nobody (including yourself) will accidentally disable your handler by overwriting the `onblur` property.

```
window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
   console.log('blur');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.onBlur = function(e) {
    // Code here.
}
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question, it is usually considered good practice to add an explanation of what your code does. This allows for developers who are not knowledgeable in this area to understand what is going on in the code and helps them to learn how to solve the problem by them selves in the future.